# Set "to" in iOS and Android when sending Facebook private message

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

For my web version, I can easily use the Facebook JavaScript SDK to do this by set the "to" field as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web#params
However, for Android and iOS, it does not seems to have "to"
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

Anyone know if it is possible to set the receiver so the user does not need to type it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/660270670746239/ it is by design and it does not seems like they will change it but I'm requesting.